# Multithreading with function in other class

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I'm new to c++ so sorry if obvious answer. I'm trying to get a thread to run a function from another class with an argument.

Here's how my code is laid out:

```
int main(){ 
    Engine engine; 
    Sounds sounds; 
    std::thread t(&Sounds::ManageSounds, &sounds, &engine) 
    /*some stuff*/
    t.join();
} 
    
class Sounds{ 
    void ManageSounds(Engine en){ 
        /*some stuff*/ 
    } 
}
```

If I run this code as is, I get this error:

> error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be
> invocable after conversion to rvalues  129 |
> typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value

If I change `ManageSounds()` to accept no arguments and remove the `&engine` in the thread, it works completely fine.

Comment: The way to fix this depends on your definition of `Engine`.  (Can it be copied?  Can it be moved?)

Comment: And *should* it be copied or moved? What are your needs?

Comment: This is not even remotely valid C++ code. Please, for a start, extract a [mcve]. It would also help if you used a thread example as a start and then tried to add one single feature, not multiple features at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread method `ManageSounds` requires an `Engine` parameter by **value**, and you pass it a **pointer** to `Engine` (&engine).

To fix it you should do one of the following:

1. Pass the `engine` object iteslf (if it is copyable, and it makes sense in your case).
2. If you actually need pointer/reference semantics (which is quite reasonable), change the thread method accordingly. In this case you need to use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) (because the ctor of `std::thread` copies the arguments). **Note:** you must ensure the thread does **not out-live** the `engine` object.

Complete code example (**using copy**):

```
#include <thread>

class Engine { /*...*/ };

class Sounds {
public:
    void ManageSounds(Engine en) {
        /*some stuff*/
    }
};

int main() {
    Engine engine;
    Sounds sounds;
    //--------------------------------------------vvvvvv
    std::thread t(&Sounds::ManageSounds, &sounds, engine);
    /*some stuff*/
    t.join();
}
```

Complete code example (**using a reference**):

```
#include <thread>

class Engine { /*...*/ };

class Sounds {
public:
    //-----------------------v
    void ManageSounds(Engine & en) {
        /*some stuff*/
    }
};

int main() {
    Engine engine;
    Sounds sounds;
    //--------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    std::thread t(&Sounds::ManageSounds, &sounds, std::ref(engine));
    /*some stuff*/
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Probably what's wanted is `std::ref`